# MSSQL auto-increment ID with Prefix

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I want to achieve an auto increment ID with prefix but resetting the number if it has different prefix.

The output I want looks like this:

```
ID  PREFIX  PROJECTID
1   PID_    PID_1
2   PID_    PID_2
3   RID_    RID_1
4   RID_    RID_2
```

But the result I got with my script is this:

```
ID  PREFIX  PROJECTID
1   PID_    PID_1
2   PID_    PID_2
3   RID_    RID_3
4   RID_    RID_4
```

Here's my script to create the table

```
CREATE TABLE PROJECTS
(ID INT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
PREFIX NVARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
PROJECTID AS ISNULL(PREFIX + CAST(ID AS NVARCHAR(10)), '') PERSISTED)

INSERT INTO PROJECTS(PREFIX) VALUES('PID_'),('PID_'),('RID_'),('RID_')
```

I'm using **MS SQL 2012**

Comment: User defined functions will help you do this

Comment: Which Version of SQL Server you are using??

Comment: In your case the best solution will depend on the version of SQL Server.

Comment: I'm using MSSQL 2012 @RajeshRanjan

MusicLovingIndianGirl - could you define what function should I use?

Comment: @Aldrin, can the prefix of the project change after it is assigned? If yes, how should a new ProjectID be assigned?

Comment: @Alex no it will not change. this prefix is for classifying where does the report belongs. We have a table that has the list of all of our reports and we want to assign an ID to each of it but with prefix. So by just looking at the prefix we will know immediately where should we look in for this report. Example prefixes is SM_ for Strategic Marketing, DD_ for Demand driver and etc.

Comment: @Aldrin Try given function bby ... :)

Comment: I am afraid there is no neat way of doing it (similar question: stackoverflow.com/questions/26374639/…). You can try these classic solutions: stackoverflow.com/a/18497115/6305294 , stackoverflow.com/a/12784166/6305294

Comment: Thanks @Alex for sharing those links as well as sharing your insights. Maybe I should just do other approach with this.

Answer (score 0):

you want like this

```
CREATE TABLE #PROJECTS
(
  ID INT IDENTITY(1, 1)
         NOT NULL ,
  PREFIX NVARCHAR(10) NOT NULL ,
  PROJECTID NVARCHAR(11)
)


INSERT  INTO #PROJECTS
    ( PREFIX )
VALUES  ( 'PID_' ),
        ( 'PID_' ),
        ( 'RID_' ),
        ( 'RID_' )
```

suppose you have above data in your table

now if you want to perform insert with DECLARE @PREFIX NVARCHAR(10) = 'RID_'

```
INSERT  INTO #PROJECTS
    ( PREFIX ,
      PROJECTID
    )
    SELECT  @PREFIX  ,
            @PREFIX  + CAST(( COUNT(TT.rn) + 1 ) AS NVARCHAR(1))
    FROM    ( SELECT    ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY P.PREFIX ORDER BY ( SELECT
                                                          NULL
                                                          ) ) AS rn
              FROM      #PROJECTS AS P
              WHERE     P.PREFIX = @PREFIX
            ) AS tt
```

see above query may helps you.

Comment: I haven't tried this but just by looking at the script, I think I should run an update query everytime I add a new record?

Answer (score 0):

Hi i found the ansowr after working couple of hours in Ms Sql server

```
USE [StocksDB]
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[tb1_triger]
ON  [dbo].[Table1]
instead of INSERT
AS 
declare @name  nchar(12)
select top 1 @name=name from inserted
declare @maxid char(12)
select @maxid = MAX(id1) from Table1

BEGIN
 SET NOCOUNT ON;
  if (@maxid is null)
  begin
   set @maxid=0
  end
   set @maxid= substring(@maxid,  5 , LEN(@maxid))+1

  INSERT INTO table1 
  (id1,name) SELECT CONCAT_WS((REPLICATE('0',12-4-LEN(@maxid))),'tblo',@maxid),i.name
  from inserted i
  END
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with an `INSTEAD OF` trigger on the table rather than using a `PERSISTED` column. I have written the trigger so that it will correctly handle bulk inserts as this is something many people overlook. Also, for my solution it is not necessary to have an `IDENTITY` column on the table if you do not want it.

So the table has been defined with the column included. Also, you can get rid of the `IDENTITY` column as I mentioned above:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.PROJECTS
(
    ID INT IDENTITY(1, 1) NOT NULL,
    PREFIX NVARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
    PROJECTID NVARCHAR(20) NOT NULL
);
```

One note - since the `PREFIX` column is `NVARCHAR(10)` and I do not know how big the numbers will get, the size of the `PROEJCTID` column was increased to prevent overflow. Adjust the size as your data requires.

Here is the trigger:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TRIGGER dbo.InsertProjects
   ON  dbo.PROJECTS
   INSTEAD OF INSERT
AS 
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    DECLARE @rowsAffected INT = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Inserted);
    -- if there are no rows affected, no need to do anything
    IF @rowsAffected = 0 RETURN;

    DECLARE @ExistingCounts TABLE (
        Prefix NVARCHAR(10) NOT NULL, 
        ExistingCount INT NOT NULL
    );

    -- get the count for each existing prefix
    INSERT INTO @ExistingCounts(Prefix, ExistingCount)
    SELECT PREFIX, COUNT(*) FROM dbo.PROJECTS GROUP BY PREFIX;

    -- since this is an INSTEAD OF trigger, we must do the insert ourself.
    -- a prefix might not exist, so use ISNULL() to get a zero in that case.

    INSERT INTO dbo.PROJECTS
    (
        PREFIX, PROJECTID
    )
    SELECT sub.PREFIX, 
        -- the number after the prefix is the existing count for the prefix plus 
        -- the position of the prefix in the Inserted table
        sub.PREFIX + CAST((sub.ExistingCount + sub.Number) AS NVARCHAR(10))
    FROM 
    (SELECT i.PREFIX,
            -- get the position (1, 2, 3...) of the prefix in the Inserted table
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY i.PREFIX ORDER BY i.PREFIX) AS [Number], 
           -- get the existing count of the prefix
           ISNULL(c.ExistingCount, 0) AS [ExistingCount]
    FROM Inserted AS i 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN @ExistingCounts AS c ON c.Prefix = i.PREFIX) AS sub;
END
GO
```

I have included comments in the source code to explain the simple logic. Hopefully this helps and is what you are looking for :-)

Answer (score -1):

Hey use this query..

```
                CREATE FUNCTION DBO.GET_NEX_P_ID(@PREF VARCHAR(4))
        RETURNS NVARCHAR(24)
        AS
        BEGIN
        RETURN  (SELECT @PREF+CAST(COUNT(1)+1 AS VARCHAR) FROM PROJECTS WHERE PREFIX=@PREF) 
        END
        GO

        CREATE TABLE PROJECTS
        (
        PREFIX VARCHAR(8),
        PROJECTID NVARCHAR(24)
        )

        GO
        INSERT INTO PROJECTS
        VALUES('PRJ_',DBO.GET_NEX_P_ID('PRJ_'))
        GO
        INSERT INTO PROJECTS
        VALUES('PRQ_',DBO.GET_NEX_P_ID('PRQ_'))
        GO
```

Thanks